# Civilization VI Resolution on Mac Retina Display

Tags: civilization-6

I recently bought Civ VI and am running it on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) with an Intel Iris Graphics 6100 graphics card and a 2560x1600 display. However, my game seems to be stuck at 1280x800, and there are no higher resolution options (the only other option is 1024x768). How do I reach these higher resolutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Civ VI does not understand or detect retina displays. However, by modifying your display resolution you can fix it. For instance, my MBP's physical resolution is 2880x1800. The default display resolution is 1440x900 retina. By setting it to 2880x1800 non-retina, I was able to get Civ VI to detect the full resolution. Doing this requires third-party software, such as EasyRes (free on the App Store), SwitchResX4 (paid with free trial) or other similar software. Once you launch Civ VI in the new resolution configuration, select the correct resolution and change UI upscaling till the UI is the correct size.

Comment: Can confirm this works on M1 machines, using EasyRes and setting to the max non-retina

Comment: For me, on M1 mac, I tinkered around the resolutions with EasyRes and in Civ6 and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It does not look like this is currently possible. From the Aspyr support page [here](https://support.aspyr.com/hc/en-us/articles/216979606-Civilization-VI-STEAM-KB):

> **Q:** Why aren’t retina display resolutions available in the Graphics Options?
>
> **A:** Retina resolution support is not yet available for Civilization VI but we're looking into updating the game to add them.  Double check that you have your System Preferences/Displays option is set to More Space to enable higher resolutions in game.

I tried manually setting the resolution in `~/Library/Application Support/Sid Meier's Civilization VI/AppOptions.txt`, but it gets overwritten the next time you launch the game. Even making the file read-only (to prevent the overwrite) doesn't seem to have any effect on the resolution. This seems to be hard-coded into the game, so for now, unfortunately, we'll have to wait for support for higher resolutions.

Answer (score 3):

I've found this to work on my M1 MacBook Air:

1. Go to: `/Users/YOURNAMEHERE/Library/Application Support/Sid Meier's Civilization VI`
2. Open `AppOptions.txt`
3. Change render width to: `RenderWidth 2560`
4. Change render width to: `RenderWidth 1440`

And those two numerical values are the native resolution of your screen. In my case it's a 27 inch 1440p/144Hz Eizo Foris, it all suddenly looked amazing.

The saved values did persist. Although the issue I have now is that Civ6 on the Apple M1 (8/8) chip is not very fast and way too frustrating to play. But that's another issue for another day.

Comment: This worked for me without the app overwriting the resolution (i launch from steam). I set it to the 'looks like' resolution from my system display's preferences.